# Is the site being more aggressive about hiding comments?

Tags: support, comments

Lately it seems that fewer comments are being shown before making you click to see them.  For example, here's a picture of a recent question for which only the first two (of three) comments were being shown when I first looked at it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's part of the new "real time updates" to the page. When a new comment is created after you have loaded the page, it shows as `"add/show X more comment(s)"`. The same is true for new answers.